# Implement Search for Google Map Android

Tags: android, google-maps, search

I've been developing an android app that requires users to be able to search for businesses on a map. To do this, I've been using the maps API and creating a google map, then using geocoder to search the map. I've been able to get this to work and be location aware.

However, the results aren't as accurate as I would like. For example, if the user searches "grocery", the results that show up aren't as accurate as those that would show up in the google maps application.

My question is, what is the best way to search the map? I've looked at the Places API, but the 100,000 searches per day limit is deterring me.

Comment: Doesn't geocoder have an even more restrictive 2,500 requests/day? Seems the answer is to use the places API.

Comment: However, this request is tied to each app installation on each individual phone, so I'm not too worried about it. However places API is 100,000 in total, so if my app gets big then that may become a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the autocomplete widget as usage limits do not apply to the widget. Check [this](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically) part of the documentation.

Comment: It seems that, "usage limits do not apply to the widget"  part removed without notice!